# Dell 6248P Powerconnect Switch - Routing IP Configuration - What is it for?

Tags: routing, ip, interface, dell, powerconnect

This is a rather simple question but I cannot seem to find a resource that explains what this feature is for (without it simply saying "this is to configure an IP interface"....very helpful)

Can someone tell me what the purpose of the interface configuration is under IP Routing? I "think" that it allows me to provide the switch itself with a secondary IP address for another subnet (a bit like sticking a second NIC into a server so it can connect to different IP ranges once assigned).

Am I completely barking up the wrong tree here?

Comment: Heh, well, that's exactly what it does. 'tho they could add a few more words: *for routing and/or management purposes*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dell 6248P is actually a Layer 3 switch, which means it can also act as a router. If you are simply using it as a Layer 2 switch, you should be able to just ignore those settings.